# Visual Studio Code Folding for Embedded Code

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to configure Visual Studio (2010/2012) to support the code folding for the server side embedded code blocks in the webform markup page like it is done in the codebehind?

Comment: Try looking at http://nuget.org/ there is always something there to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is collapse tag option [MSDN: Visual Studio 2012 collapse tag](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0c16bba8-a5e3-490f-9e2b-a2fa5a2adf7e/visual-studio-2012-collapse-tag) The controls are CTRL + M